# Why am I not getting a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I expect a `NullPointerException` in the output of the following program, because inside the `go` method, `c2` is nulled. But it works fine and print 200. Why?

```
class CardBoard {
    Short story = 200;
    CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
        cb = null;
        return cb;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
        CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
        CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
        System.out.print(c2.story); // dout here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pointing the parameter of the `go` function to null, not the `c2` variable. The `go` method might change the contents of the `CardBoard` parameter in its execution (e.g. the `story` parameter), but the object itself will not be 'nulled'.

Comment: he might also be thinking of `System.out.print(c3.story);`, which would throw a NPE, as `c3` would have been assigned the `null`.

Comment: just edited now what...?

Comment: @akf: probably, and he'd be getting a NPE there.

Comment: @user1612062: just improving the question, that's all. That's how SO works :)

Comment: @Bohemian: wow, never thought I'd make spelling mistakes like that.. Thanks for correcting me, I feel ashamed!

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [pass by value semantics](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) for method calls.  This means that the value of the reference to `c2` is passed to the `go` method, not the reference itself. Think of it this way. There are 4 memory slots, 3 containing the values that point to the objects created in `main`, these are named `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, respectively, and another that will hold the value passed into the `go` method, named `cb`.  When the function is called the value in `c2` is copied to the slot `cb`.  The `go` method then puts the value `null` in the slot `cb`. This, however, doesn't change the value in slot `c2` - it remains the same as it was before the method call.

Answer (score 1):

[Is Java pass-by-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Lets say `r2` is the reference to `c2` , lets say `123` is the value of that reference. 
so `r2` "holds" `123` which is nothing but `c2's` location.

Now when you call `c1.go(c2)`, a new reference `rN` is created which holds `123`, and is passed to the method. And when you do `c2 = null`, it is the refrence `rN` which becomes `null` and not `c2`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java parameters are passed by value, not by reference, so you are not modifying the variable `c2`, you are just "passing" the objet to which `c2` is pointing to.

Maybe if you were using a language like C# you could do this in java:

```
class CardBoard {

    Short story = 200;

    CardBoard go(byRef CardBoard cb) { // NOT REALLY ALLOWED, Compilation error
        cb = null;
        return cb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
        CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
        CardBoard c3 = c1.go(byRef c2); // NOT REALLY ALLOWED, Compilation error
        System.out.print(c2.story); // dout here
    }
}
```

then you would be modifying `c2` itself, but the only thing you could modify would be the internal state of the object that you pass (invoking something like `myObj.setSomething(x)`).

Answer (score 0):

- A *reference* to c2 is passed to the go method.
- the reference is assigned to the parameter cb
- the method code assigns a null to the parameter variable

All this has no effect on the contents of the c2 variable outside the go method

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected result try to use the

```
`System.out.print(cb.story);`
```

inside the `go` method after `nulling` **cb**.

**Or**

```
System.out.print(c3.story); // dout here
```

Now in your case you are returning `null` which is assigned to `c3`. So your are not modifying the `c2` variable.

The best explaination I have found about these doubts is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

All the answers and comments are worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstood by how reference and objects works

Main Function

```
  CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();

c1 |100| Address  ---points to---> Memory address at location 100

      CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
c2 |400| Address  ---points to---> Memory address at location 400

      CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
c3 |600| Address  ---points to---> Memory address at location 600

      System.out.print(c2.story); // dout here
```

go Function

```
 CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {

cb |400| Address  ---points to---> Memory address at location 400

New cb reference is created which also points to memory location where c2 is pointing(Note, cb and c2 are two different reference but pointing to same memory location)

     cb = null;
Above line changed cb reference to null, still c2 is pointing to same memory location.
      return cb;
  }
```

So when go function returned there is no change to c2.

Try changing story variable on cb reference, and you will see it affect to c2 variable as well.

cb is created in different method stack then where c1, c2 and c3 is created